# Tests in Python of a class that requests to REST API

Tags: python, unit-testing, microsoft-graph-api

I am working in a desktop client application that accesses the OneDrive (Microsoft Graph) REST API to download and upload files.
The Onedrive class checks if the access token needs to be renewed before each request.

Should I unit test this class? Is there a way to mock these requests?

Here is the source code of the class:

```py
import json
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

TOKEN_URL = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token'
DRIVE_BY_ID_URL = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/'
CLIENT_ID = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'

class Onedrive:

    def __init__(self, access_token, refresh_token, expire_date):
        self._access_token = access_token
        self._refresh_token = refresh_token
        self._expire_date = expire_date
        self.timeout = 5

    def download(self, drive_id, file_id, filename):
        self._renew_token()
        url = f'{DRIVE_BY_ID_URL}/{drive_id}/items/{file_id}/content?AVOverride=1'
        with open(filename, 'wb+') as fp:
            headers = {'Authorization': self._access_token}
            request = Request(url, headers=headers)
            with urlopen(request, timeout=self.timeout) as response:
                fp.write(response.read())

    def upload(self, local_path, parent_drive_id, parent_id, filename):
        self._renew_token()
        url = f'{DRIVE_BY_ID_URL}/{parent_drive_id}/items/{parent_id}:/{filename}:/content'
        headers = {'Authorization': self._access_token, "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"}
        with open(local_path, 'rb') as fp:
            data = fp.read()
            request = Request(url, headers=headers, data=data, method='PUT')
            with urlopen(request, timeout=self.timeout) as response:
                return json.load(response)

    def _renew_token(self):
        if self._expire_date <= datetime.now():
            body = f'client_id={CLIENT_ID}&refresh_token={self._refresh_token}&grant_type=refresh_token'
            self._acquire_token(body)

    def _acquire_token(self, body):
        now = datetime.now()
        request = Request(TOKEN_URL, data=body.encode(), method='POST')
        with urlopen(request, timeout=self.timeout) as response:
            data = json.load(response)
            self._access_token = data['access_token']
            self._refresh_token = data['refresh_token']
            expire = data['expires_in']
            self._expire_date = now + timedelta(seconds=int(expire))
```

Comment: You can use mock.Patch on the urllib.request.Request object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's attached how you can improve the code above:

1. First on constructor or **init** you don't need to access_token, refresh_token and expired date. To make it simple for any modules that consume this class, all of token related stuff is handled inside OneDrive Class. The class will simply get token every time you use download or upload methods. this will remove `self._renew_token()` on every other methods.

   2. You could extract line below:

```
request = Request(url, headers=headers)
with urlopen(request, timeout=self.timeout) as response:
```

Which used in few methods into his own function. this will adhere to single responsibility so later new method called `request` is the one responsible handling HTTP Request and other method that consume this method only care about the return. With this design it's also possible later in the future if you decide to change library into something else like Requests or AIOHTTP you only need to modify this method.

3. For testing, now you can just the the `request` methods by patching the urllib, and now for `upload` or `download` there's few approach you can do, you could mock the `request` or still just patch the urllib that used inside request method. I recommend that you try the unit-test (test all module and mock other module that this module relying) and later integration-test (all module connecting with other module)

onedrive.py

```
import json
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

TOKEN_URL = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token"
DRIVE_BY_ID_URL = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/"
CLIENT_ID = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx"


class Onedrive:
    def __init__(self):
        access_token, refresh_token, expire_date = self._renew_token()
        self._access_token = access_token
        self._refresh_token = refresh_token
        self._expire_date = expire_date

    @staticmethod
    def request(url, headers, method="GET", data=None):
        """
            this function handle the actual HTTP request to actual endpoint
            behind by providing url, headers, method and data
        """
        request = Request(url, headers=headers, data=data, method=method)
        with urlopen(request, timeout=5) as response:
            return response

    def download(self, drive_id, file_id, filename):
        url = f"{DRIVE_BY_ID_URL}/{drive_id}/items/{file_id}/content?AVOverride=1"
        with open(filename, "wb+") as fp:
            headers = {"Authorization": self._access_token}
            response = self.request(url, headers)
            fp.write(response.read())

    def upload(self, local_path, parent_drive_id, parent_id, filename):
        url = f"{DRIVE_BY_ID_URL}/{parent_drive_id}/items/{parent_id}:/{filename}:/content"
        headers = {
            "Authorization": self._access_token,
            "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
        }
        with open(local_path, "rb") as fp:
            response = self.request(
                url=url, headers=headers, data=fp.read(), method="PUT"
            )
            return json.load(response)

    def _renew_token(self):
        access_token = self._access_token
        refresh_token = self._refresh_token
        expire_date = self._expire_date

        if self._expire_date <= datetime.now():
            body = f"client_id={CLIENT_ID}&refresh_token={self._refresh_token}&grant_type=refresh_token"
            access_token, refresh_token, expire_date = self._acquire_token(body)
        return access_token, refresh_token, expire_date

    def _acquire_token(self, body):
        now = datetime.now()
        response = self.request(
            url=TOKEN_URL, headers=None, data=body.encode(), method="POST"
        )
        data = json.load(response)

        access_token = data["access_token"]
        refresh_token = data["refresh_token"]
        expire = data["expires_in"]
        expire_date = now + timedelta(seconds=int(expire))

        return access_token, refresh_token, expire_date
```

test_onedrive.py

```
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch, MagicMock
from example import Onedrive


class TestOneDrive(TestCase):
    @patch("urllib.request.urlopen")
    def test_request(self, mock_urlopen):
        mock = MagicMock()
        mock.getcode.return_value = 200
        mock.read.return_value = "some-contents"
        mock.__enter__.return_value = mock
        mock_urlopen.return_value = mock

        response = Onedrive.request(
            url="https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token",
            headers={"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"},
            method="POST",
            data={"data": "some_data"},
        )

        self.assertEqual(response.getcode(), 200)
        self.assertEqual(response.read(), "some-contents")

    @patch("urllib.request.urlopen")
    def test_download(self, mock_urlopen):
        mock = MagicMock()
        mock.getcode.return_value = 200
        mock.read.return_value = "some-contents"
        mock.__enter__.return_value = mock
        mock_urlopen.return_value = mock

        Onedrive().download(
            drive_id="drive-id", file_id="file_id", filename="some_filename"
        )

        # now you just check whether the file actual written
```

reference:
https://docs.python.org/3/howto/urllib2.html
https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html